# Flutter : Why future builder don't run what inside snapshot.hasData? Edited

Tags: flutter, dart, future, builder

I made many test apps but this time I don't know why I get this error :
I have this Future function with future builder inside state less widget :

```
Future<List> getDegrees() async {
      var url =
          'https://xxxxxx/api/controller/activities/activiy_list.php?d_id=$dId&m_id=$courseId&u_id=$uId';

      var response = await http.get(url);

      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      for (var x in data) {
        Digree newdigree = Digree(
            x['index'],
            x['title_k'],
            x['title_a'],
            x['aya'],
            x['link'],
            x['activity_k'],
            x['activity_a'],
            x['act_id'],
            x['mydigree']);
        digrees.add(newdigree);
      }
      return digrees;
    }

    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getDegrees(),
        // ignore: missing_return
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError || snapshot.data == null) {
            return WillPopScope(
                // ignore: missing_return
                onWillPop: () async {
                  Navigator.of(context)
                      .pushReplacementNamed('weeks', arguments: {
                    'courseId': courseId,
                  });
                },
                child: Scaffold(
                    appBar: AppBar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.pink[900],
                      title: Text(
                        'ژیان و قورئان',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
                      ),
                      centerTitle: true,
                    ),
                    body: Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              image:
                                  AssetImage('./assets/images/background.png'),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 100,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 100,
                            width: 100,
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                              strokeWidth: 5,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Loading ......",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )));
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return WillPopScope(
                // ignore: missing_return
                onWillPop: () async {
                  Navigator.of(context)
                      .pushReplacementNamed('weeks', arguments: {
                    'courseId': courseId,
                  });
                },
                child: Scaffold(body: Container(child: Text('welcome'))));
          }
        });
```

I checked many time I didn't found my mistake , When I print the received list inside the function it is print correctly ,but when I display it in future builder it don't work ,where is my problem ?

### The problem is : Future Builder just run CircularProgressIndicator .
Any Help?

Comment: please post the full error

Comment: Don't hide return errors with `ignore: missing_return`. That warning tells you when a method that is supposed to return something isn't always returning something. For example, in your `FutureBuilder`, you have it returning something when `snapshot.hasError || snapshot.data == null` and when `snapshot.hasData`, but that build method won't return anything if neither of those things are true which will result in a Flutter error. Warnings are there for a reason, so don't hide them unless you have a VERY good reason.

Comment: sorry may I change my question

Comment: Thanks for you I made changes in question

Comment: Which list are you printing correctly, `data` or `digrees`?

Comment: I printed data list

Comment: Maybe instead of `snapshot.data == null`, use `!snapshot.hasData` and remove the `else if` condition checking as it is unnecessary.

Comment: it is same just run the CircularProgressIndicator

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the `Digree newDigree = Digree(...)` line.  If something in that constructor throws an error, the `Future` completes with an error instead of data.

Comment: @Nitrodon I get this Exception : The following RangeError was thrown building FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(dirty, dependencies:
[MediaQuery], state: _FutureBuilderState<List<dynamic>>#28644):
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
The relevant error-causing widget was:
FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>

Comment: the problem is solved after I get the Exceptions I found the error ,it was in my class ,String value was double